# Identification: animated TV series 2000-2005, possibly canadian, using "Right here, right now" music

Tags: story-identification, tv

Please help me identify a sci-fi cartoon TV series from the 2000. One of the most salient feature of the series was the rock/electronic music used in the background, and especially the famous [Right here, right now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_Here,_Right_Now_%28Fatboy_Slim_song%29) of Fatboy Slim. Thus, the series must have been produced after 1999, when the music was released, and I always thought it was Canadian or French. Apart the unusual music background, I don't remember much - only that one of the main characters was a kind of alien princess. The main starship was doing some kind of service and was part of a larger union, if I remember well. The images were quite complex, similar but with more detail than in anime movies. The series was aired on one of the French main TV channels sometime in the 2002-2006.

I know the description is very vague, but I'm sure that if I see an image with the characters I will be able to identify them.

Comment: Osmosis jones had it

Comment: Are you thinking of Tripping The Rift? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripping_the_Rift

Comment: Thank you for answering. I found Tripping the Rift when actively searching, but it's not that one (although Tripping look very hilarious). The one I'm searching has also a different type of drawing, more cartoonish and less cgi.

Comment: Oh - I found it. I was apparently mistaken about the music. The movie is a French one, aired probably on the M6 channel and is called: [Malo Korrigan and the Space Tracers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malo_Korrigan), 2003. The sound track is original and important for the series "feeling" and part of it can be heard on a page about the composers ([Deep Forest](http://www.deepforest.co/news_malo-korrigan.htm)).

Comment: @Cocofifi - I'm glad you managed to find it. You can add an answer to your own question, and accept it in due course.

Comment: I was not sure about that. Thank you. Done, although I don't have enough reputation to add all the links as links. But it should be fine, if anyone searches for that series.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer by an inelegant approach - skimming the list of 1294 animation series and movies in the science fiction and space category on [Animeka](http://www.animeka.com/animes/genres/espacescifi.html), a French site about animation. The list had the advantage of showing small pictures along the description of the series or movie.

I was apparently mistaken about the music. The movie is a French one, aired probably on the M6 channel and is called: [Malo Korrigan and the Space Tracers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malo_Korrigan), 2003. The sound track is original and important for the series "feeling" and part of it can be heard on a page about the composers (Deep Forest - www.deepforest.co/news_malo-korrigan.htm).

Funny thing is that asking the question here, was the additional motivation needed to do the search the way finally got a result. The movie was produced by Futurikon - www.futurikon.com, a very reputable French studio, who's also better known for the Minuscule series and movie - www.imdb.com/title/tt2368672/.